# How to slice scraped xml data and create lists in python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, slice

I am looking for a faster way to create the 'times' and 'temps' lists created below. As you can see, I had to create the lists item by item since I couldn't figure out how to slice the lists or create a for loop to make them.

For example, with:

```
'time = f_soup.forecast.select('time')[0:]'

'time[0]['from']' - #works to select a single item, but
'time[0:3]['from']' - #causes "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
```

The data is a web scrape of Edmonton's 5 day forecast from https://openweathermap.org/forecast5.

I've included everything else below:

```
#f = Forecast
f = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
q=Edmonton&mode=xml&units=metric&&appid=########################')
f_text = f.text

f_soup = BeautifulSoup(f_text, "lxml-xml")
print(f_soup.prettify())

time = f_soup.forecast.select('time')[0:]
times = [
    datetime.strptime(time[0]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime(time[1]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime(time[2]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime(time[3]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime(time[4]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    datetime.strptime(time[5]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    ...
    ...
    datetime.strptime(time[39]['from'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    ]

temp = f_soup.forecast.select('temperature')[0:]
temps = [
    float(temp[0]['value']),
    float(temp[1]['value']),
    float(temp[2]['value']),
    float(temp[3]['value']),
    float(temp[4]['value']),
    float(temp[5]['value']),
    ...
    ...
    float(temp[39]['value'])
    ]
```

below is a snippet of one of the time tags of the xml I am trying to grab:

```
<forecast>
  <time from="2021-01-18T21:00:00" to="2021-01-19T00:00:00">
   <symbol name="clear sky" number="800" var="01n"/>
   <precipitation probability="0"/>
   <windDirection code="WNW" deg="288" name="West-northwest"/>
   <windSpeed mps="3.9" name="Gentle Breeze" unit="m/s"/>
   <temperature max="0.65" min="-1.73" unit="celsius" value="0.65"/>
   <feels_like unit="celsius" value="-4.5"/>
   <pressure unit="hPa" value="1026"/>
   <humidity unit="%" value="75"/>
   <clouds all="0" unit="%" value="clear sky"/>
   <visibility value="10000"/>
  </time>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Any comments on how to improve the code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be [better](https://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) to just use xml.etree than BeautifulSoup for this and you could achieve your result like this:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
f = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Edmonton&mode=xml&units=metric&&appid={api_key}'.format(api_key=api_key))

# parse the result text directly to the XML parser
tree = ET.fromstring(f.text)

times = []
temps = []

# iterate through the XML tree element by element
for elem in tree.iter():
    # is it a time tag then extract the time and date from the 'from' attribute
    if elem.tag == 'time':
        times.append(datetime.strptime(elem.get('from'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')) # append result to list

    if elem.tag == 'temperature':
        # is it a temperature tag then extract the value from the 'value' attribute
        temps.append(elem.get('value')) # append result to list

print(times)
print(len(times))
print(temps)
print(len(temps))
```